# Mathematical Induction

Tags: induction

I have to prove my mathematical induction that $5^n - 1$ is divisible by 4. for all non negative $n ≥ 0$. My solution is the following.

**Base case:** When $n = 0, 
 5^n-1 = 5^0-1 = 0$.
Base case holds for $n = 0.$

**Induction Hypothesis**: Assume the property holds for $n = k$, i.e. $5^k-1$ is divisible by $4$.

**Induction Step**: When $n = k + 1$, we must prove that $5^{k+1}-1$ is divisble by $4$.

$5^{k+1}-1 = 5 * 5^k-1$

From the hypothesis we know that $5^k-1$ is divisible by $4$. Any number divisible by $4$ and multiplied by $5$ is divisible by $4$.

Thus $5^{k+1}-1$ is divisible by $4$.

***The actual answer booklet offers a solution that seems unnecessarily complex.***

$5^{k+1} -1 = 5*5^{k-1}$

$= 5 *(5^k-1+1)-1$

$= 5 * (5^k - 1 ) + 5 - 1$

$= 5 * (5^k - 1) + 4$

By the induction hypothesis, $5k - 1$ is divisible by $4$. Clearly $4$ is also divisible by $4$ and therefore $5 ∗ (5 k − 1) + 4$ is divisible by $4$ and the induction step is proven.

Is my way of doing it correct or is it not complete enough?

Thanks.

Comment: Your argument is incorrect because $5 \cdot 5^k - 1 \neq 5(5^k-1)$.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi $5 * 5^k - 1 = 5^{k+1} -1$ What is wrong with this?

Comment: Nothing wrong up to that point. What you cannot do is then claim that you got $5(5^k-1)$ instead and therefore you can apply the induction hypothesis directly to the expression in parentheses to finish the proof.

Comment: I couldn't provide any background on that. As you can see this is the solution offered to the problem. So my way of solving this is OK?

Comment: No, it's obviously not.  You just made a trivial algebra mistake that invalidates your argument.  The conclusion is obviously right.  Your argument is not.

Comment: Again, everything below the line written in bold where it says that the solution comes from the answer booklet comes from the answer booklet and not from me. I will edit my post so you it can seem clearer.

Comment: I perfectly understand that.  The part below the line was correct.

Comment: Oh got you. Would you care pointing out again where the mistake is here? I cannot see it. Thank you

Comment: OK. One last try.  $5 \cdot 5^k - 1$ is not the product of $5$ and a multiple of $4$.  That would be $5(5^k-1)$ and that's why the answer key does what it does.

Comment: Oh that makes sense. Sorry and thanks for taking the time.

Comment: No problem.  As a side note, you should convince yourself that $5^n -1$ is never a multiple of $5$.

Answer (score 2):

without induction it is simple, $$5\equiv 1 \mod 4$$ thus we have $$5^n\equiv 1 \mod 4$$

Comment: Thanks, but I interested in solving this with induction

Answer (score 0):

Your induction hypothesis can simply imply that $5^k-1=4M$, where $M$ is an integer. Then it will be more clear for your presentation

Answer (score 0):

Extra work : separate it to $n=2k+1,n=2k $ odd and even 
for $n=2k$ we have 
$$5^n-1=5^{2k}-1=\\(5^k-1)(5^k+1)=(odd-odd)(odd+odd)=\\even .even=2q.2m=4Q (**) \checkmark$$
for $n=2k+1$ we have 
$$5^{2k+1}-1=5.5^{2k}-1=\\5.(5^{2k}-1)+4\\from(**)\\=5(4Q)+4\\=4Q'$$

Answer (score 0):

$5^n,n>1$ ends with $25$ so that $5^n-1$ ends with $24$, which is divisible by $4$

Comment: This is correct but the question is to use induction.

Comment: @T. Gunn, thanks. this is an alternative method, which can also be proven by induction...